# How to use webBrowser control in c# to get user google latitude and longitude?

Tags: c#, .net, google-maps-api-3, webbrowser-control

Can I use c# webrowser control to get latitude and longitude using google javascript api v3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use any javascript API from Google to get geocode data. Simply use the WebRequest object and read the result from the XML file provided by the geocode service.

```
WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("your adress");
WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
```

From there, you can get the Stream and create a StreamReader as follow:

```
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
```

After that, simply decode the XML by using the element tag "lat" and "lng".
You should then be able to get the data you are looking for.

For more information, and particulary the terms of service for using the Google Geocode Service, visit the Google Maps API website.

Comment: I cannot provide address. I want to know the user location without address.

Comment: are developping an app on a mobile device? you might need to look to some GPS API or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
            string strSelect = textBoxGpsLatitude.Text;
            strSelect += ",";
            strSelect += textBoxGpsLongitude.Text;

            webBrowser3.Navigate("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + strSelect, false);
```